# $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$: 1st Stiefel Whitney class v.s. fermion eta invariant v.s. spin structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, spin-geometry, cobordism

$H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ specifies the 1st cohomology class of manifold $M$ (can be regarded as spacetime) with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficient,

it is often to see that we say the 1st Stiefel Whitney class

> $$w_1 \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2), \tag{1}$$

However, it looks to me that when we discuss the spinor bundle (associated to fermion in physics), we also say that the fermion line is related to $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2).$ For example, on the $d$-torus, we need to specify the spin structure on the torus (a spin manifold, with possibly the choice of $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)=H^1(T^d,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\bigoplus_d\mathbb{Z}_2$ along each $S^1$-circle direction.) In other words, we may say that roughly

> $$\text{periodic and anti-periodic boundary condition of fermions} \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2),\tag{2}$$

Moreover, one way to understand the fermion moving along a 1-dimensional sub dimensional manifold, may be the spin bordism group generator, say $\eta$, where

> $$\Omega^{1,Spin}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}_2,\tag{2},$$

where $\eta$ on a nontrivial 1-dimensional manifold generates the bordism group.

> My question: So how are these eq.(1), (2), (3) are related? Or how are they not related? Can one clarify these with examples?

Answer (score 5):

The set of isomorphism classes of spin structures on a spin manifold $M$ is a torsor over $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$; what this means is that $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ acts freely and transitively on it, so the two can be identified but not canonically. An identification requires a choice of spin structure to act as the "origin." The $n$-torus happens to have a close-to-canonical choice of spin structure given by the one coming from its Lie group framing, so one can make a close-to-canonical identification in that case.

I don't know how this is related to fermions or spin bordism.

Comment: Can you clarify  "the two can be identified but not canonically" -- what specified the differences? Also what is a close-to-canonical identification? What is a  canonical identification?

Comment: I asked a new question and add eq 4 in MO, because I want to know the spin bordism group part: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377522/the-first-stiefel-whitney-class-v-s-fermion-eta-invariant-v-s-spin-structure-v

Comment: @annie: I mean what I said in the next sentence - that to pick an identification between the two requires a choice of spin structure to act as the "origin." "Close-to-canonical" is not a rigorous technical term; I just mean there's a distinguished choice that e.g. I wouldn't be surprised if it appeared in the literature as the "default" one. "Canonical" is not a rigorous technical term either and is a very complicated concept to make precise but loosely it means "not arbitrary."

Comment: can I phrase what you say in this way: suppose I have a $A \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $B \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, then to compare the two 1st cohomology classes -- I can compare the difference of the two which gives rise to a $w_1 \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (that is the reference frame?) Where can I find precise discussions on this on which paper or which Sec of textbooks?

Comment: @annie: I mean that the difference of two spin structures is an element of $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. You might try looking in Lawson and Michelson's *Spin Geometry*.

Comment: @annie: the same phenomenon already occurs one level down for orientations; the set of orientations of an orientable real vector bundle is a torsor over $H^0(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$, meaning that the difference between two such orientations is an element of $H^0(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Comment: Thanks, "the difference of two spin structures is an element of 1(,ℤ2)." But isnt that the the spin structures is also an element of 1(,ℤ2)??? (This is part of the whole point of my puzzle.)

Comment: @annie: what I am saying is precisely that that is not true. To pick an identification between the set of spin structures and $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ requires a choice of spin structure to act as the "origin," as I have already said twice. Many people are not careful about this but it really does matter; for example, there may be a group acting on $M$ which does not fix the spin structure you chose as the "origin."

Comment: Thanks -- this rings my bell - it really helps!!!  <3

Comment: @annie: you're welcome! This is subtle stuff. Here's an example (involving equivariant complex spin structures, so not quite the same but similar) where this kind of thing shows up: https://mathoverflow.net/a/199194/290

Comment: If I know spin structures, then what is complex spin structures? what is equivariant spin structures?

Comment: Well, never mind then, it was just supposed to be an example.